# Django CharField None vs empty string global default standardization

Tags: django, string, null

It is always a pain to do this to get objects with **not** Null:

```
Object.objects.filter(some_field__isnull=False).exclude(some_field='')
```

Or this to get objects with **only** Null:

```
Object.objects.filter(Q(some_field__isnull=True) | Q(some_field=''))
```

---

By default it is Null, but if empty form submitted, it becomes empty string..

---

Is there any practice in Django to set CharField behaviour somehow uniformly by default, somehow easy and globally? To never think about this in development?

*Probably it is not about Django, but, anyway*

Comment: In my opinion this should be handled in the view wherever you handle the form data. You should store the data in the correct format to make queries easy. So if it's an empty string, make sure it is stored as Null, not `''`.

Comment: @MarcusLind The awesomeness of Django is that lots of forms and their views including admin forms are generated and not under control, and it is not "easy and global" solution

Comment: Avoid using `null=True` for `CharField` and `TextFIeld`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#null "If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string."